# Version 1 UUID Node.js binding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid

I was trying to export https://github.com/LiosK/UUID.js into a module, but I'm having a rough time - version 4 is worthless to me (use case Cassandra) - does anybody know of a binding for these types of uuids? I can't seem to find one on Google...maybe someone has implemented what's out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use /dist/uuid.core.js with a slight modification as follows:

add the following line and save:

exports.UUID = UUID;

now in another file use:

var UUID = require("path/to/the/uuid.core.js");

console.log(UUID.generate());

hope that helps
J

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid now supports v1 format IDs. FWIW.